# Wait socket response in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, nsstream

I am using socket for send and receive data runtime but in some cases, i still need to wait the response from server.
In http request, i use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    });
});
```

In another way, i using socket and have a request to server `CheckVersion`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //check update version 
}
```

After that, i have to wait response from socket. If version is no longer support, an alertview should show and prevent the FirstViewController show.

How could i wait socket response?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using `AFNetworking`?

Comment: I used to using AFNetworking for async loading UIImage in TableView. But in my case, i am using TCP Socket instead HTTP request, so it is not suitable for using AFNetworking

Comment: OK [CococAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) then.